# Will JWT authorizer in aws HTTP API gateway cache Public key to avoid repeated call to Authorisation server

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-jwt-authorizer

Will JWT authorizer in  aws HTTP API gateway cache Public key to avoid repeated call to Authorisation server ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. It is documented in the part explaining how cognito keys are cached by API Gateway:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-caching-tokens.html